# How to default a date field to a particular day of the week?

Tags: 2010, date-time, default-value

When a new list item is added, I'd like a date field (Date From) to be defaulted to Monday of this week, as well as another date field (Date To) to Sunday of next week (creating a 1 week span Mon-Sun). So no matter what day of the week it currently is, these date fields would default to this week's date range.

Can I accomplish this using just the column's default value? If so, how?

Please note I barely know anything about SharePoint and am learning as I go, so I'd prefer a method which doesn't require programming (even though I'm willing to do so if I have to).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What a fun problem! For column LastMonday:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY([Created])=1,DATE(YEAR([Created]),MONTH([Created]),DAY([Created])-6),DATE(YEAR([Created]),MONTH([Created]),DAY([Created])-WEEKDAY([Created])+2))
```

For column NextSunday:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY([Created])=1,[Created],DATE(YEAR([Created]),MONTH([Created]),DAY([Created])-WEEKDAY([Created])+8))
```

You can do this as a default value of a date column if you want users to be able to change it, or just make a calculated column of data type "Date and Time", "Date Only" if you don't.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! When I get back to work tomorrow I'll plug it in.

Comment: I couldn't wait until tomorrow to try, so I remoted into work and tried, adding it as the default value "Calculated Value" copying your text, but I get an error: `The formula contains reference(s) to field(s).`

Comment: @jerry Change [Created] to [Today] in your formula, otherwise, you'll have to create a calculated column.

Comment: That made it work! Now just because I like to ensure everything is accounted for before I consider something done, I need to wait until tomorrow anyway to make sure the "Date From" really shows Monday, because Today is Monday :D

Comment: Good that I had a chance to test it on Monday though, because at least I know Mondays will always default to that same Monday and not the previous or next