# SharePoint 2010 - specific day before date

Tags: 2010, calculated-column-formula

What I would like is a calculation that would take return the value of the Thursday before my [TargetDate] value.  If it is on a Thursday, it too has to be the Thursday before.  This is to make sure that the form is submitted before the target date.

I found this, but looks like I'd have to do a WEEKDAY statement for every day of the week

[How to default a date field to a particular day of the week?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79499/how-to-default-a-date-field-to-a-particular-day-of-the-week)

Can't seem to wrap my head around this one!  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This should get the job done:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY([TargetDate])<=5,[TargetDate]-WEEKDAY([TargetDate])-2,[TargetDate]-WEEKDAY([TargetDate])+5)
```

Comment: Do I put this into a 'calculated' or 'date and time' column?  I tried 'calculated' with returned data being single line and date, and 'date and time' with the default view being calculated - they all give me a 'syntax error or not supported' error.  The only change I had made was [TargetDate] to [Target Install date] as follows:  =IF(WEEKDAY([Target Install date])<=5;[Target Install date]-WEEKDAY([Target Install date])-2;[Target Install date]-WEEKDAY([Target Install date])+5)  Where should I put the formula?

Comment: This has been tested in Excel, so please try it now in calculated column (with comma instead of semicolon). Make sure that in calculated column you set `The data type returned from this formula is: ` Date and Time.

Comment: Perfect solution!  Thank you Slaven!  Out of curiosity, would you know how to make the date Wednesday if Thursday is a holiday (like upcoming Christmas!)?

Comment: Handling holidays is more complex and cannot be solved with calculated column alone. You would have to implement custom code.